# Apache Tika 1.16 TXTParser Failed to detect character encoding in sbt build

Tags: scala, sbt, jena, apache-tika, sbt-assembly

I am building a project that I had in Eclipse using sbt assembly. I have a very large and complex build.sbt file as I had many conflicts.

Everything works correctly for pdf, pptx, odt and docx files using the PDF, OOXML and OpenDocument parsers in tika 1.16. However when I try to parse a txt file (UTF-8 encoded) using the TXTParser I get the following error:

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Failed to detect the character encoding of a document
    at org.apache.tika.detect.AutoDetectReader.detect(AutoDetectReader.java:77)
    at org.apache.tika.detect.AutoDetectReader.<init>(AutoDetectReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.tika.detect.AutoDetectReader.<init>(AutoDetectReader.java:114)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser.parse(TXTParser.java:79)`
```

from this line in my Scala code:

```
val content = theParser.parse(stream.open(), chandler, meta, pContext)
```

where stream is a PortableDataStream, chandler is a new BodyContentHandler, meta is a new Metadata and pContext is a new ParseContext.

If I use AutoDetectParser instead I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jena.shared.SyntaxError: unknown
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.NTripleReader.read(NTripleReader.java:73)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.NTripleReader.read(NTripleReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:305)
```

from this line in my Scala code:

```
val response = model.read(stream, null, "N-TRIPLES")
```

where stream is an InputStream.

I think this is due to an empty response from Tika (so the same problem).

I am pretty sure this is probably a dependency issue in my over-complex build.sbt file but after many hours of trying, I definitely need help.

One positive is that everything works perfectly if no txt file is input so this is likely my last issue!

Finally, here is my build.sbt file that I build using `sbt clean assembly`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
version      := "1.0.0"
name := "crawldocs"
conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.addlesee.crawling.CrawlHiccup")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.tika" % "tika-core" % "1.16",
  "org.apache.tika" % "tika-parsers" % "1.16" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "guava")
  ),
    "com.blazegraph" % "bigdata-core" % "2.0.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "collection-0.7"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-csv"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-io"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-lang3"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-logging"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient-cache"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpcore"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpmime"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-annotations"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-core"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-databind"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jcl-over-slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jena-cmds"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jena-rdfconnection"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jena-tdb"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jsonld-java"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "libthrift"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "log4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "xercesImpl"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "xml-apis")
  ),
    "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena" % "3.4.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-csv"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-lang3"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient-cache"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpcore"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-core"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-databind"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jcl-over-slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jena-rdfconnection"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api")
  ),
    "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "3.4.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-csv"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-lang3"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient-cache"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpcore"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-core"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-databind"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jcl-over-slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jena-rdfconnection"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api")
  ),
    "org.noggit" % "noggit" % "0.6",
    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api")
  ),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "breeze_2.11"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-hdfs"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-annotations"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-common"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-mapreduce-client-app"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-mapreduce-client-common"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-yarn-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-yarn-client"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-yarn-common"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-yarn-server-common"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "activation"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "hive-exec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "scala-compiler"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "spire_2.11"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-compress"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "guava"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-io"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "gson"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "zookeeper"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jettison"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-core"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpcore"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "bcprov-jdk15on"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jul-to-slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jcl-over-slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "curator-framework")
  ),
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-xml" % "2.11.0-M4",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.7.3" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-io"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jettison"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "avro"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-compress"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "netty")
  ),
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.3" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-codec"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-cli"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-api"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-math3"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-io"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jets3t"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "gson"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "avro"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "httpclient"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "zookeeper"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-compress"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "slf4j-log4j12"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "commons-net"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "curator-recipes"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jsr305")
  )
)
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: If you grab the Tika App standalone jar, and try with that, is it able to process your file? That'll tell you if it's a Tika bug, or a problem with how you're including Tika in your project

Comment: In my Eclipse project I had the tika-app and tika-parsers standalone jars in my build path. That worked perfectly... I have tried having only the tika-app dependency in my build.sbt but I can't remember the problem. I will test again and post it here on Tuesday (I require a service not available at home to test the built jar). Thanks for your response!

Comment: MergeStrategy.concat looks like the right one for "META-INF/service/* (I do not use sbt).

Comment: Ok, I have modified my build.sbt to have tika-app as a dependency instead of core and parsers. It runs exactly the same annoyingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed...

I added `case x if x.contains("EncodingDetector") => MergeStrategy.deduplicate` ABOVE the discard line in the MergeStrategy. The following assemblyMergeStrategy at the bottom of my build.sbt fixes my issue:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case x if x.contains("EncodingDetector") => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Could you help by telling how to resolve this issue in java?

Answer (score 2):

The code above calls the old N-triples parse that exists only for legacy reasons. The old reader is ASCII only. UTF-8 will break it.

Either `apache-jena-libs` (which is type=pom) is not being handled, or you are repacking jars and haven't handled the META-INF/service where Java's ServiceLoader puts files. Jena uses this for initialization. You must combine META_INF/service/* files by concatenating ones of the same name.

Details: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html

Comment: I'm not ignoring this, I just cannot test this until Tuesday as the built jar requires a service that I don't have access to from home. I do have a couple of questions:

How do the other files work with the N-triples parser when the txt's have problems?

Should I try adding the maven-shade-plugin as a dependency?

I handle the META-INF merging at the bottom of my build.sbt with a first strategy. Should I modify that?

Thank you for your help and link!

Comment: MergeStrategy.concat looks like the right one for "META-INF/service/*" (though I don't use sbt)

Comment: That produced the following error:

`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file` I will try other merge strategies.

Comment: That is a serious error of the platform. The merge must result in multiple lines `META-INF/services/org.apache.jena.system.JenaSubsystemLifecycle`

Comment: I have been messing with the merge strategy by adding lines like `case x if x.contains("txt") => MergeStrategy.concat` but haven't found the correct classes to concatenate yet. Do you know which class it is that I need to put in the quotes?

Comment: I don't use sbt.

Comment: Fair enough, I was more asking whether you knew which class I am needing to concatenate. (i.e. what text would go in the quotation marks). If you know that would be amazing but no worries if you don't, you've sent me in the right direction!

Comment: I found it and posted an answer. It was a Tika problem with my merge strategy. Thanks again for your time!